# 3d permutation matrices

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, linear-programming, polytopes, latin-square

$8 \times 8$ permutation matrices correspond to patterns of 8 rooks on a chessboard
with exactly 1 rook in each row or column, never 2.

Consider patterns of $n^2$ "3d rooks" in an $n \times n \times n$ cube,
with exactly 1 rook in each of the $3n^2$ lines parallel to the $x, y, z$ axes.
Two equivalent descriptions:

- each plane cross section is an $n \times n$ permutation matrix
- $n^3$ bits, binary variables $x_i$, which solve the $3n^2 \times n^3$
  system of linear equations $Ax = 1$ where $A$ for $n=3$ looks like this:

  [111........................]
  [...111.....................]
  [......111..................]
  [.........111...............]
  [............111............]
                  ...
  [1..1..1....................]
  [.1..1..1...................]
  [..1..1..1..................]
  [.........1..1..1...........]
  [..........1..1..1..........]
              ...
  [[1........1........1........]
  [.1........1........1.......]
  [..1........1........1......]
  [...1........1........1.....]
  [....1........1........1....]
        ...

My questions:

1. what are these objects called -- is there a standard name, other descriptions ?
2. about how many different $n \times n \times n$ such patterns are there ?
3. about how many different vertices / extreme points does the convex polytope
   $\{x: Ax = 1, 0 \leq x \leq 1 \}$ have ?

(Background: to generate test cases for linear programming, continuous not binary,
the 2d
[assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem),
is too easy -- $1000 \times 1000$ runs in about a minute
with the opensource GLPK simplex solver.
Extended Latin squares, the above in 4d not 3d, give LP problems
that run for hours: see
[many-vertex-test-problems-for-the-simplex-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936789/many-vertex-test-problems-for-the-simplex-method) on SO.)

Comment: These are exactly equivalent to Latin squares! To get the corresponding Latin square, for each coordinate $(i,j,k)$ in the cube where a $1$ is located, label row $i$ and column $j$ in the Latin square with symbol $k$.

Answer (score 1):

What [Mike Earnest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370934/3d-permutation-matrices#comment6936569_3370934) said in the comments is correct:

> These are exactly equivalent to Latin squares! To get the corresponding Latin square, for each coordinate (i,j,k) in the cube where a 1 is located, label row i and column j in the Latin square with symbol k.

Thus the number of such $n \times n \times n$ cubes is equal to the number of Latin squares of order $n$

Jacobson and Matthews, [*Generating Uniformly Distributed
Random Latin Squares*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/%28SICI%291520-6610%281996%294%3A6%3C405%3A%3AAID-JCD3%3E3.0.CO%3B2-J), J. Comb. Des. (1996) called this

- ***the incidence-cube representation of a Latin square*** or
- ***incidence cube*** for short.

(I have no idea about the third question.)